# postgres 9.3 json array of strings to text

Tags: json, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.3, the json_array_elements function returns each string element in an array as json strings.

```
select value from json_array_elements('["a", "b"]');

value 
-------
"a"
"b"
```

I would like to convert these to regular Postgres TEXT values but I'm at a loss. I tried value::TEXT but they are still double quoted, i.e. json strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u want this.

```
select REPLACE(value::TEXT,'"','') from json_array_elements('["a", "b"]');
```

Comment: That was what I was hoping to avoid. Resorting to REPLACE seems like a workaround for doing something wrong in the first place. My use case is a one-shot schema migration script so this is ok. I'd still like to see a "cleaner" solution.

Comment: I guess as " is treat like a text so u will not be able to get data without replacing it.

Comment: I went with this since the clean and correct way was only added in postgres 9.4 in the form of the json_array_elements_text function.

Answer (score 10):

As simple as:

```
select value from json_array_elements_text('["a", "b"]');
```

Comment: This would be the way to go IF one were using postgres 9.4+

Comment: The way to go would be to upgrade then {;-)